# How should fontspec be set up to exploit the best features of Pro fonts?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, fontsize

Suppose that you have a Pro class fonts such as `Adobe Arno` which has several design sizes as described below:

```
Design    Size  Size Ranges             
Caption:   8    point 5–8.5 point
SmText:   10    point 8.6–11
Regular:  12    point 11.1–14 point
Subhead:  18    point 14.1–21.5 point
Display:  36    point 21.5+ point
```

Arno Pro is supplied as set of the following font files:

```
ArnoPro-Bold.otf
ArnoPro-BoldCaption.otf
ArnoPro-BoldDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-BoldItalic.otf
ArnoPro-BoldItalicCaption.otf
ArnoPro-BoldItalicDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-BoldItalicSmText.otf
ArnoPro-BoldItalicSubhead.otf
ArnoPro-BoldSmText.otf
ArnoPro-BoldSubhead.otf
ArnoPro-Caption.otf
ArnoPro-Display.otf
ArnoPro-Italic.otf
ArnoPro-ItalicCaption.otf
ArnoPro-ItalicDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-ItalicSmText.otf
ArnoPro-ItalicSubhead.otf
ArnoPro-LightDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-LightItalicDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-Regular.otf
ArnoPro-Smbd.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdCaption.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdItalic.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdItalicCaption.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdItalicDisplay.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSmText.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdItalicSubhead.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdSmText.otf
ArnoPro-SmbdSubhead.otf
ArnoPro-SmText.otf
ArnoPro-Subhead.otf
```

> How should one setup `fontspec`
>   package to exploit best features of these fonts?

Starting code is here:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic,Ligatures={TeX}]{ArnoPro}
```

Would it be sufficient? I am not sure that `Caption` version of these fonts will be invoked by the `\small` or `\footnotesize` switches. What should one add here?

**Added at 2nd edit**

I mean that in standard LaTeX classes font size declarations are bounded to optical sizes according to the following table:

```
 declaration \ class option  10pt      11pt       12pt

 \tiny                        5pt       6pt        6pt
 \scriptsize                  7pt       8pt        8pt
 \footnotesize                8pt       9pt       10pt
 \small                       9pt      10pt       11pt
 \normalsize                 10pt      11pt       12pt
 \large                      12pt      12pt       14pt
 \Large                      14pt      14pt       17pt
 \LARGE                      17pt      17pt       20pt
 \huge                       20pt      20pt       25pt
 \Huge                       25pt      25pt       25pt
```

Hence, for `10pt` class option, `\tiny`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize` should switch to Arno Pro Caption, `\small`, `\normalsize` to Arno Pro SmText, `\large` and `\Large` to Arno Pro, `\LARGE` and `\huge` to Arno Pro Subhead, and `\Huge` to Arno Pro Display. All these fonts are actually diffrent, when scaled to same size, so that Caption version looks better for `\footnosize` than Regular vesrion.

Comment: Looks good to me; is there anything going wrong? (Of course, it depends how lucky you are that the optical sizes have been found automatically.)

Comment: @Igor: These fonts are designed almost only for literary books, and didn't go well for mathematics and physics books. For English, or other Latin alphabet based language, they are acceptable to some degree. But for Russian mathematics and physics books - please don't use them. They are too far from what the Russian reader is trained to read. And that will create a learning overhead until the reader gets familiar with the font. Ну просто не подходят эти шрифты. :)

Comment: @Karl, suppose that Arno Pro breaks some traditions in Russian science books, though I don't know which tradiations namely it breaks. Advice, please, then what fonts are good for Russian books.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow exactly, but XeTeX and (I hope!) luaotfload when using LuaTeX should respect the optical size info and select them automatically. I'll attempt an example tomorrow if I have time...

Comment: Arno, Minion and Garamond are [Old style Serifs](http://www.paratype.com/help/class/desc.asp?hg=11), по русский [Антиква старого стиля](http://www.paratype.ru/help/class/desc.asp?hg=11). While the two fonts used in almost all Soviet and Russian math and physics books, namely Literaturnaya (Литературная) and New Standard (Обыкновенная новая) are respectively...

Comment: ...[Latin serif](http://www.paratype.com/help/class/desc.asp?hg=15) = [Антиква латинского стиля](http://www.paratype.ru/help/class/desc.asp?hg=15) and [Modern Serif](http://www.paratype.com/help/class/desc.asp?hg=13) = [Антиква нового стиля (классицистическая)](http://www.paratype.ru/help/class/desc.asp?hg=13). Computer Modern is similar to New Standard and is Modern Serif too. Times New Roman is somewhat similar to Literaturnaya, although it is Transitional Serif (Переходная Антиква), not Latin Serif. So, in short Old style Serifs are uncommon for Russian.

Comment: @Karl: I've got Arno with Cyrillic alphabet, so your statement that there is no Russian Old Style Serif is now outdated. Actually, I am limited by existing math fonts, they should have same style as text fonts. From this consideration, Literaturnaya, by my opinion, is not good choice. Currently, I in the beginning of font selection for my book. Your comment and links are very usefull. Thanks.

Comment: No, there was many, and there are many Cyrillic Old Style Serifs, even Russian made (Arno isn't Russian made, even it's possible that the font designer knows only the alphabet, not the language) if you look at the links. But the tradition says - nobody uses Old Style Serifs in math books. Lazurski for example, but it's for literary books. Literaturnaya or it's better variant Quant Antiqua are in fact used by ФИЗМАТЛИТ (fml.ru). And you are right - it doesn't match CM well.

Comment: If you want a really good looking and matching text and math fonts there aren't many choices. CM + CM math; MinionPro + Minion Math; Times (or variant of Times) + MathTime. All other fonts - either the text font lacks Cyrillic, or the math font is rather imperfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer to my question occurred to be rather simple. There is no need to invent sophisticated font loading procedure. `fontspec` package occurred to be smart enough to select correct font shape for every size. To check that one need to run the following simple test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
\setmainfont{Arno Pro}

\begin{document}%
\newcommand{\MyText}{No offence meant, I even upvoted your answer.}

\verb|\tiny|=\tiny\MyText\par
\verb|\scriptsize|=\scriptsize\MyText\par
\verb|\footnotesize|=\footnotesize\MyText\par
\verb|\normalsize|=\normalsize\MyText\par
\verb|\large|=\large\MyText\par
\verb|\Large|=\Large\MyText\par
\verb|\LARGE|=\LARGE\MyText\par
\verb|\huge|=\huge\MyText\par
\verb|\Huge|=\Huge\MyText\par

\end{document}
```

Then I exported the compiled PDF to MS World and saw that `\tiny` `\scriptsize` and `\footnotesize` are typed by Arno Pro Caption  as it should be, and `\normalsize` is typed by Arno Pro SmText  as expected, e.c.t.

> Great!

Unfortunately, LuaLaTeX on my computer [Version beta-0.70.1-2011052811 (rev 4277)  (format=lualatex 2011.6.23)] did not manage to compile that short example, but XeLaTeX have  that done very quickly.

Comment: Actually it's XeTeX that automatically selects the optical sizes. But you can use fontspec to fine tune things if necessary (the syntax is a bit verbose, though).

Answer (score 3):

it also  works with `lualatex` but it takes *a lot of time* for `luatex` to create the cache for the font files:

```
...
(load: /home/voss/.texlive2011/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/temp-ar
nopro-display.lua)(save: /home/voss/.texlive2011/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic
/fonts/otf/temp-arnopro-display.lua)
Overfull \hbox (15.88963pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 17--17
[][][]\EU2/lmtt/m/n/20.74 \Huge\EU2/ArnoPro(0)/m/n/20.74 =\EU2/ArnoPro(0)/m/n/2
4.88 No of-fence meant, I even up-voted
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./latex6.aux) )
 275 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 attribute, 40 glue_spec, 3 attribute_lis
t, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:1551,3:13,4:158,5:179,6:470,7:2,9:34,10:27
</home/voss/.fonts/ArnoPro/ArnoPro-Display.otf></home/voss/.fonts/ArnoPro/ArnoP
ro-Subhead.otf></usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmm
ono12-regular.otf></home/voss/.fonts/ArnoPro/ArnoPro-Regular.otf></usr/local/te
xlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono8-regular.otf></home/voss/
.fonts/ArnoPro/ArnoPro-Caption.otf></home/voss/.fonts/ArnoPro/ArnoPro-SmText.ot
f></usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmmono10-regular
.otf>
Output written on latex6.pdf (1 page, 33812 bytes).

Transcript written on latex6.log.
```

I used current TeXLive2011 pretest:

```
voss@shania:~/Documents> lualatex -v
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011061410 (rev 4277)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've used the approach of simply inserting `\setmainfont{Arno Pro}[Numbers={Lowercase,Proportional}]` for years to load Arno Pro, and it almost always works perfectly. But I've been using Overleaf lately, which [requires loading fonts from a local project](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F), plus I wanted to use the Light weights for especially large text in a particular document, so I came up with this to specify the exact ranges and names of the optical sizes. Here, the optical sizes are taken from the [Adobe specimen book for Arno Pro](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/type/pdfs/ArnoPro.pdf), but using the Light Display weight for type above 36pt is my judgement:

```latex
\setmainfont{ArnoPro}[
  % Path = {./fonts/}, % use to load from a `fonts` folder in your project
  Extension = {.otf},
  UprightFont = {*-Regular},
  ItalicFont = {*-Italic},
  BoldFont = {*-Smbd},
  BoldItalicFont = {*-SmbdItalic},
  Numbers={Lowercase,Proportional},
  UprightFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
      {Size={-8.5},      Font=*-Caption},
      {Size={8.6-10.99}, Font=*-SmText},
      {Size={11-14},     Font=*-Regular},
      {Size={14.1-21.59},Font=*-Subhead},
      {Size={21.6-35.99},Font=*-Display},
      {Size={36-},       Font=*-LightDisplay}
    },
  },
  ItalicFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
      {Size={-8.5},      Font=*-ItalicCaption},
      {Size={8.6-10.99}, Font=*-ItalicSmText},
      {Size={11-14},     Font=*-Italic},
      {Size={14.1-21.59},Font=*-ItalicSubhead},
      {Size={21.6-35.99},Font=*-ItalicDisplay},
      {Size={36-},       Font=*-LightItalicDisplay}
    },
  },
  BoldFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
      {Size={-8.5},      Font=*-SmbdCaption},
      {Size={8.6-10.99}, Font=*-SmbdSmText},
      {Size={11-14},     Font=*-Smbd},
      {Size={14.1-21.59},Font=*-SmbdSubhead},
      {Size={21.6-},     Font=*-SmbdDisplay}
    },
  },
  BoldItalicFeatures={
    SizeFeatures={
      {Size={-8.5},      Font=*-SmbdItalicCaption},
      {Size={8.6-10.99}, Font=*-SmbdItalicSmText},
      {Size={11-14},     Font=*-SmbdItalic},
      {Size={14.1-21.59},Font=*-SmbdItalicSubhead},
      {Size={21.6-},     Font=*-SmbdItalicDisplay}
    },
  }
]
```