# Disabling ligatures also disables kerning

Tags: microtype, ligatures, kerning, minionpro

I am using Adobe Minion Pro (mostly because of its maths support), but I don't want to use the 'Th' ligature. This decision is based on guidance from Bringhurst's *Elements of Typographic Style*.

I have tried using `microtype` to disable any ligatures starting with 'T', but this also seems to affect kerning pairs starting with 'T'. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minionpro}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\DisableLigatures[T]{}

\begin{document}
Th
To
\end{document}
```

When I don't modify the default behaviour of `microtype`, the output looks like this

[image]

But when I uncomment `\DisableLigatures[T]{}`, I get this output:

[image]

This separates the 'Th' ligature successfully, but is no longer any kerning on 'To' (kerning for other characters appears to be unaffected).

How do I disable the 'Th' ligature without interfering with the kerning?

Comment: Since Th is not *that* common, I would define a macro `\Th`. When you end your document, and you are going to send/print it, just do a Search for `Th` & Replace for `\Th ` (with a trailing space) and that's all.

Comment: @Manuel using a `\Th` macro is a good idea. I should mention that many of my sentences begin with 'The', so the ligature is actually quite common in my documents. Perhaps this is a problem with my writing style, rather than LaTeX!

Comment: I mean it's the most trivial way: you have no problem with defining `\makeatletter \newcommand*\Th{T\penalty\@M\hskip\z@ h} \makeatother`.

Comment: Is the problem specific to Minion Pro? It would help to know which engine you are using. Minion Pro seems to include various... er... quirks....

Comment: @cfr I am using pdfLaTeX. Does the 'Th' ligature exist in other LaTeX fonts? I haven't seen it anywhere other than Minion Pro...

Comment: Do you mean the problem is that specific? If you disabled ligatures for 'f', say, kerning would be unaffected?

Comment: Yes. With `\DisableLigatures[f]{}` the kerning between the pair 'fe' is still definitely negative (although it is reduced by a whisker).

Comment: This is a known limitation in `pdftex` (inherited from `tex` itself): information on ligatures and on kerning is stored in the same table in the font metrics, therefore one cannot switch off ligatures or kerning independently from one another.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If switching from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX is an option for you, you could employ the [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package to disable the `Th` ligature globally, while leaving all other ligatures in place. (To disable the operation of `selnolig` at some point in the document, issue the command `\selnoligoff`.)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
%%\setmathfont{Minion Pro Math} % check name of math font 
\usepackage{selnolig} % load selnolig w/o a language option
\nolig{Th}{T|h} % disable "Th" ligature globally
\begin{document}
The That Thick Though, Tantrum Test To Tub

\medskip
with \verb+selnolig+ disabled:

\selnoligoff
The That Thick Though, Tantrum Test To Tub
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Mico. Your `selnolig` package is very well-designed, and probably provides the most elegant solution to my problem. But for now I am reluctant to use LuaLaTeX (it compiles very slowly on my computer), so I will probably just put up with the 'Th' ligature.

Comment: @onewhaleid - Thanks for the compliment! Sorry to read that LuaLaTeX is slow on your system. It's not on mine (MacOSX 10.10.1 "Yosemite", MacTeX2104). What's your TeX setup like? Only the very first time that Lua(La)TeX is run should be slow, because that's when various font cache databases have to be built. After the first run, further compilations should run very quickly. Have you maybe inadvertently set a switch that forces LuaLaTeX to rebuild the font cache files every time?

Comment: My experience with LuaLaTeX is similar to that described in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75118/why-does-it-take-lualatex-so-long-to-load-fonts-and-can-i-speed-it-up

Comment: @onewhaleid Speed has improved with the latest versions of `lualatex` as included in texlive 2014.